# How to display datetime in dd/MMMM/yyyy format in Html.DropDownList?

Tags: .net, datetime, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

This is my view :

[image]

Instead of displaying it like that, I want it to be displayed in `dd/MMMM/yyyy` format.

My code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedDate",(SelectList)ViewBag.AptDates,new { @class = "form-control 0:dd/MMMM/yyyy" })
```

Why the format isn't changing? The DropDownList is been populated with data from database.

Thanks

Comment: It appears AptDates is a SelectList being created somewhere else in your code. Why not just format it when you create the SelectList?

Comment: Yes, that worked. Easy fix that way. Thanks!!

Comment: Great. I will go ahead and post an answer with that recommendation for future visitors to this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it appears that `AptDates` is already a `SelectList` being generated elsewhere in your code. This is important because the `SelectList` class already provides you with a mechanism for specifying both your Display Text as well as your Value.

I would recommend simply modifying the logic used to generate your `SelectList` to output the Display Text in a format that you want shown in your `DropDownList`. This will save you some time and headache down the road, instead of having to specify custom formatting on each of your `DropDownList` implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Change to the Method which has logic behind populating SelectList:

```
foreach(var date in AvailableDates)
        {
            Dates.Add(date.Schedual.ToString("dd/MMMM/yyyy hh:mm tt"),date.Appt_Id);
        }
        // selectlist => list,value,id
        ViewBag.AptDates = new SelectList(Dates);
```